# PostgreSQL: How to select 2 different counts from table when x=a and x=b

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, where-clause, having

Dear fellow Stackoverflowers,

How may one select 2 different counts from the same table for scenarios:

```
x=a and x=b
```

specifically, (WHEN type = subdomain) AND (WHEN subtype = subdomain)?

to add them together to create a 'totalcount'?

My attempt (for your reference):

```
SELECT description, type, count(1), subtype, count(2) 
FROM mapping, (dotcom WHERE type = subdomain) AS typecount, 
     (dotcom WHERE subtype = subdomain) AS subtypecount 
GROUP BY description, type, subtype 
HAVING count(1)>1 
AND count(2)>1 
ORDER BY count(*) 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

Second attempt:

```
SELECT description
FROM mapping, SUM(WHEN subdomain = type OR subdomain = subtype) AS count(1)
GROUP BY description, type, subtype 
HAVING count(1)>1 
ORDER BY count(*) 
DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Maybe with some `SUM(WHEN  type = subdomain THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: I need the SUM to increment when type and subtype = subdomain, so maybe SUM(WHEN type OR subtype = subdomain THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;) <- is this possible?

Comment: You could also try using Count(distinct type), Count(distinct subtype)

Comment: How may I fit that into the big picture?

Comment: "type OR subtype = subdomain" won't work, but you could use "type = subdomain OR subtype = subdomain"

Comment: interesting, thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can show some sample data and what the expected results should be?  This seems like an interesting question, but I don't fully understand it.  On the surface, it seems like something that definitely can be done

Answer (score 1):

If you have Postgres 9.4 or newer, you can use `FILTER`, which is much easier to read than the `CASE WHEN ... END` syntax.

```
SELECT
  description, 
  type,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE subdomain = type) AS typecount,
  subtype,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE subtype = subdomain) AS subtypecount
FROM mapping
GROUP BY description, type, subtype;
```

It should be noted that `count(1)` and `count(2)` doesn't do what you probably think it does; `count` is an aggregate function that counts if the given value is not null in each row, and seeing as you're giving it an integer literal, it will effectively only count the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, You can do like below

```
SELECT description, SUM(CASE WHEN subdomain = type OR subdomain = subtype THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM mapping
GROUP BY description
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT
      SUM(
          CASE WHEN type = 'whatever'
              THEN column_name_1
              ELSE coumn_name_2
          END AS column1,
          CASE WHEN subtype = 'whatever2'
             THEN column_name_3
             ELSE coumn_name_4
          END AS column2
      )
```